# how to overlay shapefile and raster?

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, gdal, spatial-statistics

I have a shapefile with polygons. And I have a global raster file. I want to overlay the shapefile's polygons onto the raster grid and calculate the mean raster value for each polygon.

How can I do this using GDAL, writing the results to the shapefile?

Comment: Is GDAL the only tool you'd like to use?

Comment: @Simbamangu no, basically anything is fine, and it would be great if it were in Python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following [advice](http://www.mail-archive.com/gdal-dev@lists.osgeo.org/msg14389.html) I got on the gdal-dev mailing list, I used [StarSpan](https://github.com/Ecotrust/starspan):

```
starspan --vector V --raster R1 R2 ... --stats mystats.csv avg mode
```

The results are saved to CSV format. At that time, that was already enough for me, but it should be possible to somehow forge a Shapefile from that info.

Comment: StarSpan seems to have moved to GitHub. Get it [here](https://github.com/Ecotrust/starspan).

Answer (score 9):

In R you can do

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
r <- raster('raster_filename')
p <- readOGR('shp_path', 'shp_file')
e <- extract(r, p, fun=mean)
```

e is a vector with the mean of the raster cell values for each polygon.

Comment: This is R not python as asked in the question

Answer (score 5):

The following script allows you to do the task with GDAL:
http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#calculate-zonal-statistics

```
# Calculates statistics (mean) on values of a raster within the zones of an polygon shapefile

import gdal, ogr, osr, numpy

def zonal_stats(input_value_raster, input_zone_polygon):

    # Open data
    raster = gdal.Open(input_value_raster)
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    shp = driver.Open(input_zone_polygon)
    lyr = shp.GetLayer()

    # get raster georeference info
    transform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
    xOrigin = transform[0]
    yOrigin = transform[3]
    pixelWidth = transform[1]
    pixelHeight = transform[5]

    # reproject geometry to same projection as raster
    sourceSR = lyr.GetSpatialRef()
    targetSR = osr.SpatialReference()
    targetSR.ImportFromWkt(raster.GetProjectionRef())
    coordTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(sourceSR,targetSR)
    feat = lyr.GetNextFeature()
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    geom.Transform(coordTrans)

    # Get extent of geometry
    ring = geom.GetGeometryRef(0)
    numpoints = ring.GetPointCount()
    pointsX = []; pointsY = []
    for p in range(numpoints):
            lon, lat, z = ring.GetPoint(p)
            pointsX.append(lon)
            pointsY.append(lat)
    xmin = min(pointsX)
    xmax = max(pointsX)
    ymin = min(pointsY)
    ymax = max(pointsY)

    # Specify offset and rows and columns to read
    xoff = int((xmin - xOrigin)/pixelWidth)
    yoff = int((yOrigin - ymax)/pixelWidth)
    xcount = int((xmax - xmin)/pixelWidth)+1
    ycount = int((ymax - ymin)/pixelWidth)+1

    # create memory target raster
    target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', xcount, ycount, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform((
        xmin, pixelWidth, 0,
        ymax, 0, pixelHeight,
    ))

    # create for target raster the same projection as for the value raster
    raster_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    raster_srs.ImportFromWkt(raster.GetProjectionRef())
    target_ds.SetProjection(raster_srs.ExportToWkt())

    # rasterize zone polygon to raster
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], lyr, burn_values=[1])

    # read raster as arrays
    banddataraster = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    dataraster = banddataraster.ReadAsArray(xoff, yoff, xcount, ycount).astype(numpy.float)

    bandmask = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    datamask = bandmask.ReadAsArray(0, 0, xcount, ycount).astype(numpy.float)

    # mask zone of raster
    zoneraster = numpy.ma.masked_array(dataraster,  numpy.logical_not(datamask))

    # calculate mean of zonal raster
    return numpy.mean(zoneraster)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your script, I tried to run it but at the end it doesn't produce anything. How to visualize the statistics?

Answer (score 4):

Load your shapefile and your raster in PostGIS 2.0 and do:

```sql
SELECT (ST_SummaryStats(ST_Clip(rast, geom))).*
FROM rastertable, geomtable
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think GDAL is the best tool for this, but you can use gdal_rasterize to "clear" all the values outside the polygon.

Something like:

```
gdal_translate -a_nodata 0 original.tif work.tif
gdal_rasterize -burn 0 -b 1 -i work.tif yourpolygon.shp -l yourpolygon
gdalinfo -stats work.tif
rm work.tif
```

The gdal_rasterize program modifies the file, so we make a copy to work on.  We also mark some particular value (zero in this case) to be nodata.  The "-burn 0 -b 1" means burn a value of zero into band 1 of the target file (work.tif).  The "-i" means invert rasterization so we burn values *outside* the polygon instead of inside it.  The gdalinfo command with -stats reports on band statistics.  I believe it will exclude the nodata value (which we marked earlier with -a_nodata).

Answer (score 2):

Transform the shape file in raster by gdal_rasterize and the use the code in http://www.spatial-ecology.net/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:geo_tools to calculate zonal statistic for each polygon. You can run http://km.fao.org/OFwiki/index.php/Oft-reclass if you want obtain a tif with your rasters statistic. 
Enjoy the code 
Ciao Giuseppe

Comment: Do you happen to have a copy of the code you refer to? Unfortunately the link to the Python file is dead.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use  [rasterstats](https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/) thas is a Python module designed for this purpose:

```
from rasterstats import zonal_stats
listofzones = zonal_stats("polygons.shp", "elevation.tif",
            stats="mean")
```

[image]

Then you can access the attribute of the first zone using:

```
mean_of_zone1 = listofzones[0]['mean']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using GDAL. You could use other free tools however, eg saga gis:

```
saga_cmd shapes_grid "Grid Values to Shapes" -GRIDS=grid.sgrd -POLYGONS=in.shp -SHAPES=out.shp-NODATA -TYPE=1
```

Comment: I went with this approach, though the function name is actually "Grid Statistics for Polygons".

Answer (score -2):

you can use calculate point statistics tool in arc gis and this tool can be download from http://ianbroad.com/arcgis-toolbox-calculate-point-statistics-polygon-arcpy/

Comment: "The Calculate Point Statistics tool takes an input Polygon and Point feature class and uses a selected field to find the minimum, maximum, and average of the points and adds the results to the polygon feature." but this question is about a Polygon feature class and a Raster so it seems unlikely to be suitable.