# Issue Trying to create Zonal Statistics using Gdal and Python.

Tags: python, gdal, open-source-gis, zonal-statistics, rasterization

I am trying to create zonal statistics using Python and Gdal. I have a polygon shapefile and a raster file, and in order to do so, I am using a piece of code I found in StackExchange.

The raster and shapefile used can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4ypd0N58np5ZVIyWWc4YThGUlE&usp=sharing)

Here is the code I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding: utf-8

## Code from Stack Exchange: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21888/how-to-overlay-shapefile-and-raster
## User: ustroetz

# Calculates statistics (mean) on values of a raster within the zones of an polygon shapefile

import gdal, ogr, osr, numpy

def zonal_stats(input_value_raster, input_zone_polygon):



 # Open data
    raster = gdal.Open(input_value_raster)
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    shp = driver.Open(input_zone_polygon)
    lyr = shp.GetLayer()

    # get raster georeference info
    transform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
    xOrigin = transform[0]
    yOrigin = transform[3]
    pixelWidth = transform[1]
    pixelHeight = transform[5]

    # reproject geometry to same projection as raster
    sourceSR = lyr.GetSpatialRef()
    targetSR = osr.SpatialReference()
    targetSR.ImportFromWkt(raster.GetProjectionRef())
    coordTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(sourceSR,targetSR)
    feat = lyr.GetNextFeature()
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    geom.Transform(coordTrans)

    # Get extent of geometry
    ring = geom.GetGeometryRef(0)
    numpoints = ring.GetPointCount()
    pointsX = []; pointsY = []
    for p in range(numpoints):
            lon, lat, z = ring.GetPoint(p)
            pointsX.append(lon)
            pointsY.append(lat)
    xmin = min(pointsX)
    xmax = max(pointsX)
    ymin = min(pointsY)
    ymax = max(pointsY)

    # Specify offset and rows and columns to read
    xoff = int((xmin - xOrigin)/pixelWidth)
    yoff = int((yOrigin - ymax)/pixelWidth)
    xcount = int((xmax - xmin)/pixelWidth)+1
    ycount = int((ymax - ymin)/pixelWidth)+1


    # create memory target raster
    target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', xcount, ycount, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform((
        xmin, pixelWidth, 0,
        ymax, 0, pixelHeight,
    ))

    # create for target raster the same projection as for the value raster
    raster_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    raster_srs.ImportFromWkt(raster.GetProjectionRef())
    target_ds.SetProjection(raster_srs.ExportToWkt())

    # rasterize zone polygon to raster
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], lyr, burn_values=[1])

    # read raster as arrays
    banddataraster = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    dataraster = banddataraster.ReadAsArray(xoff, yoff, xcount, ycount).astype(numpy.float)

    bandmask = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    datamask = bandmask.ReadAsArray(0, 0, xcount, ycount).astype(numpy.float)

    # mask zone of raster
    zoneraster = numpy.ma.masked_array(dataraster,  numpy.logical_not(datamask))

    # calculate mean of zonal raster
    return numpy.mean(zoneraster)
```

However, when I implement it, the output (numpy.mean(zoneraster)) is just a number and not an array or a raster. What am I missing? Is there something wrong with the files imput? The code?

Comment: The output is supposed to be only a number. The number is the mean of the raster of the area covered by your shapefile. What are you expecting to be in the array? You can find an updated version of my script [here](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#calculate-zonal-statistics).

Comment: I thought the code would create the mean value of my input raster _for each_ polygon of my input shapefile. Therefore I was expecting to have, as an output something of the flavour:

`[['polygon_label1', 'mean_raster1'],...,['polygon_labeln',mean_rastern']]`

And by the way, thank you for posting that code!

Comment: If you have many polygons, you need to rasterize them by some ID and then iterate over the unique IDs.  You can accumulate the statistical output as a look-up table which you can join back to your zonal polygons.  If speed becomes an issue as a result of the iteration use SciPy.ndimage instead of numpy.  It is a couple of orders of magnitude faster in my experience.

Comment: Do you know how I could loop over each polygon of the shapefile?

Comment: I was looking for a script to do exactly this task, but, when trying it I've realized that averages are calculated over the whole bbox defined by each polygon in the shape layer. gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], lyr, burn_values=[1]) I don't really know if I am missunderstanding the code (I have seen the same approach in the oficial python gdal/ogr cookbook), or if it's in fact an error. However, any idea on how to parse just the feature instead of the whole layer in the mentione line? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get zonal statistics for several features in one shapefile, you have to loop over the `zonal_stats` function. You can write the results of the loop for example to a dictionary. Below is the modified `zonal_stats` function together with a loop, looping over the input shapefile. As an output you get a Dictionary containing for each Feature ID the mean of the covered raster.

For your sample dataset the dictionary for the first five features looks like this

```
{0: 114.57909872798288, 1: 21.889622561136882, 2: 287.79623686237102, 3: 35.350804240486838, 4: 19.63043032511781}
```

The two functions:

```
import gdal, ogr, osr, numpy


def zonal_stats(feat, input_zone_polygon, input_value_raster):

    # Open data
    raster = gdal.Open(input_value_raster)
    shp = ogr.Open(input_zone_polygon)
    lyr = shp.GetLayer()

    # Get raster georeference info
    transform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
    xOrigin = transform[0]
    yOrigin = transform[3]
    pixelWidth = transform[1]
    pixelHeight = transform[5]

    # Get extent of feat
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    if (geom.GetGeometryName() == 'MULTIPOLYGON'):
        count = 0
        pointsX = []; pointsY = []
        for polygon in geom:
            geomInner = geom.GetGeometryRef(count)    
            ring = geomInner.GetGeometryRef(0)
            numpoints = ring.GetPointCount()
            for p in range(numpoints):
                    lon, lat, z = ring.GetPoint(p)
                    pointsX.append(lon)
                    pointsY.append(lat)    
            count += 1
    elif (geom.GetGeometryName() == 'POLYGON'):
        ring = geom.GetGeometryRef(0)
        numpoints = ring.GetPointCount()
        pointsX = []; pointsY = []
        for p in range(numpoints):
                lon, lat, z = ring.GetPoint(p)
                pointsX.append(lon)
                pointsY.append(lat)

    else:
        sys.exit()

    xmin = min(pointsX)
    xmax = max(pointsX)
    ymin = min(pointsY)
    ymax = max(pointsY)

    # Specify offset and rows and columns to read
    xoff = int((xmin - xOrigin)/pixelWidth)
    yoff = int((yOrigin - ymax)/pixelWidth)
    xcount = int((xmax - xmin)/pixelWidth)+1
    ycount = int((ymax - ymin)/pixelWidth)+1

    # Create memory target raster
    target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', xcount, ycount, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform((
        xmin, pixelWidth, 0,
        ymax, 0, pixelHeight,
    ))

    # Create for target raster the same projection as for the value raster
    raster_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    raster_srs.ImportFromWkt(raster.GetProjectionRef())
    target_ds.SetProjection(raster_srs.ExportToWkt())

    # Rasterize zone polygon to raster
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], lyr, burn_values=[1])

    # Read raster as arrays
    banddataraster = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    dataraster = banddataraster.ReadAsArray(xoff, yoff, xcount, ycount).astype(numpy.float)

    bandmask = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    datamask = bandmask.ReadAsArray(0, 0, xcount, ycount).astype(numpy.float)

    # Mask zone of raster
    zoneraster = numpy.ma.masked_array(dataraster,  numpy.logical_not(datamask))

    # Calculate statistics of zonal raster
    return numpy.mean(zoneraster)


def loop_zonal_stats(input_zone_polygon, input_value_raster):

    shp = ogr.Open(input_zone_polygon)
    lyr = shp.GetLayer()
    featList = range(lyr.GetFeatureCount())
    statDict = {}

    for FID in featList:
        feat = lyr.GetFeature(FID)
        meanValue = zonal_stats(feat, input_zone_polygon, input_value_raster)
        statDict[FID] = meanValue
    return statDict



# Raster dataset
input_value_raster = 'popc_0ADProj.tif'
# Vector dataset(zones)
input_zone_polygon = 'borders_tribes.shp'

print loop_zonal_stats(input_zone_polygon, input_value_raster)
```

Comment: I have another issue with the code in the section `#get extent of geometry`. My features can be  multiple polygons. 
Here's my output for `geom.GetGeomRef(i)`, where `i' is each value of `geom.GetGeometryCount()`:

`DATABASE:     7
LINEARRING (0.980468987882861 8.28964924042946, ...,
0.980468987882861 8.28964924042946)
DATABASE:     8
POLYGON ((43.148330027378911 11.721389243497216,...,
 11.72443924429683,43.148330027378911 11.721389243497216))`
I modified the code to deal with these special cases (code written in next comment) but typically, it won't deal with polygons like "Database 8".

Comment: My modified section is as follows:
`# Get extent of geometry
geonumbers=geom.GetGeometryCount()
xmin_all=[]
(...)
ymax_all=[] 
for i in range(geonumbers):
 ring_i = geom.GetGeometryRef(i)
 numpoints = ring_i.GetPointCount()
 print ring_i
 pointsX_i = []; pointsY_i = []
 for p in range(numpoints):
  lon, lat, z = ring_i.GetPoint(p)
  pointsX_i.append(lon)
  pointsY_i.append(lat)
 xmin_all.append(min(pointsX_i))
 xmax_all.append(max(pointsX_i))
 ymin_all.append(min(pointsY_i))
 ymax_all.append(max(pointsY_i))
xmin=min(xmin_all)
xmax=max(xmax_all)
ymin=min(ymin_all)
ymax=max(ymax_all)
`

Comment: @Doon_Bogan I modified the function, so that it accepts polygons and multipolygons. I test run it with your sample dataset and it worked fine. Thanks for catching that bug. Please let me know if it works now for you.

Comment: How to the "# Get extent of feat " step is different than using GetEnvelope() on feature geometry object ? I think it will automatically take care of "Polygon" or "MultiPolygon".

Answer (score 8):

With multiprocessing, for fastness! Has a little different output-formatting.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import gdal, ogr, osr, numpy, sys
from multiprocessing import Pool


# Raster dataset
input_value_raster = sys.argv[1]

# Vector dataset(zones)
input_zone_polygon = sys.argv[2]

# Open data
rast = gdal.Open(input_value_raster)
shp = ogr.Open(input_zone_polygon)

# Get raster georeference info
transform = rast.GetGeoTransform()
xOrigin = transform[0]
yOrigin = transform[3]
pixelWidth = transform[1]
pixelHeight = transform[5]

def proc(fid):

    # Each process needs its own pointer it seems.
    shape = ogr.Open(input_zone_polygon)
    lyr = shape.GetLayer()
    feat = lyr.GetFeature(fid)
    raster = gdal.Open(input_value_raster)

    # Get extent of feat
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    if (geom.GetGeometryName() == 'MULTIPOLYGON'):
        count = 0
        pointsX = []; pointsY = []
        for polygon in geom:
            geomInner = geom.GetGeometryRef(count)    
            ring = geomInner.GetGeometryRef(0)
            numpoints = ring.GetPointCount()
            for p in range(numpoints):
                    lon, lat, z = ring.GetPoint(p)
                    pointsX.append(lon)
                    pointsY.append(lat)    
            count += 1
    elif (geom.GetGeometryName() == 'POLYGON'):
        ring = geom.GetGeometryRef(0)
        numpoints = ring.GetPointCount()
        pointsX = []; pointsY = []
        for p in range(numpoints):
                lon, lat, z = ring.GetPoint(p)
                pointsX.append(lon)
                pointsY.append(lat)

    else:
        sys.exit()

    xmin = min(pointsX)
    xmax = max(pointsX)
    ymin = min(pointsY)
    ymax = max(pointsY)

    # Specify offset and rows and columns to read
    xoff = int((xmin - xOrigin)/pixelWidth)
    yoff = int((yOrigin - ymax)/pixelWidth)
    xcount = int((xmax - xmin)/pixelWidth)+1
    ycount = int((ymax - ymin)/pixelWidth)+1

    # Create memory target raster
    target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', xcount, ycount, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform((
        xmin, pixelWidth, 0,
        ymax, 0, pixelHeight,
    ))

    # Create for target raster the same projection as for the value raster
    raster_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    raster_srs.ImportFromWkt(raster.GetProjectionRef())
    target_ds.SetProjection(raster_srs.ExportToWkt())

    # Rasterize zone polygon to raster
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], lyr, burn_values=[1])

    # Read raster as arrays
    banddataraster = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    dataraster = banddataraster.ReadAsArray(xoff, yoff, xcount, ycount).astype(numpy.float)

    bandmask = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    datamask = bandmask.ReadAsArray(0, 0, xcount, ycount).astype(numpy.float)

    # Mask zone of raster
    zoneraster = numpy.ma.masked_array(dataraster,  numpy.logical_not(datamask))

    # Calculate statistics of zonal raster
    value = numpy.max(zoneraster)
    #print value
    return str(fid)+": "+str(value)


# Start the processes
layer = shp.GetLayer()
featList = range(layer.GetFeatureCount())
pool = Pool(processes=24)   
print pool.map(proc,featList,8)
```